# D'Alembert's Ratio Test.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

D'Alembert's Ratio Test says that if for a series $\sum a_{n}$ of non negative reals and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=R$$ then the series $\sum a_{n}$  converges  if $R<1$ and diverges if $R>1$. Now my question is what  if $R=\infty?$  I am thinking that if $R=\infty>1$ so divergent. Am i right?  Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Typo? Should be "$R = \infty > 1$ so _divergent_", which is true.

Comment: yes i edited thanks....

Comment: Example: $a_n = n!$, so it can't be convergent in general.

Comment: but its a single example...

Comment: Yes, $\infty>1$. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is divergent. When $R>1$, $a_n\not\to0$. This is also true for $R=\infty$.

Comment: how its true for $R= \infty$?

Comment: How do you prove "when $R>1$, $a_n\not\to0$"?

Comment: @neela Well, $\infty >> 1$.

Comment: but i was thinking like that . $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: When $R>1$, didn't you pick an $R'$ such that $R>R'>1$?

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\infty$, then you can find $\bar{n}$ such that, for all $n\ge\bar{n}$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge2$. Therefore $a_{\bar{n}+k}\ge2^ka_{\bar{n}}$ and the series diverges by comparison with a clearly divergent series.